# Bokeh: How to loop through CheckboxButtonGroup

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to loop through the button objects in a `CheckboxButtonGroup` in bokeh?

I want to loop through each button in the group and assign them different `on_click` handlers depending on their label. I was envisioning something like:

```
for button in checkbox_button_group:
    button.on_click(someHandlerFunc)
```

But obviously a CheckboxButtonGroup object is not iterable. Looking the documentation I cannot find to find an attribute that returns the actual button objects within the group. I see the `active` attribute and the `labels` but that doesn't seem like that is what I want.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.groups.html#bokeh.models.widgets.groups.AbstractGroup

Answer (score 2):

In the checkboxgroup callback, just get the index or label of the active button. Then do a if/elif/else chain of statements calling whatever function you want associated with each button.

**EDIT:** here are some simple things with button groups:

To just do something with the last button clicked

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import CheckboxButtonGroup

a = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=list('012'),active=[])

def stuff_0(in_active):
    if in_active:
        print 'do stuff'
    else:
        print 'undo stuff'
def stuff_1(in_active):
    if in_active:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
def stuff_2(in_active):
    if in_active:
        print 'banana'
    else:
        print 'apple'

stuff_list = [stuff_0,stuff_1,stuff_2]

def do_stuff(attr,old,new):
    print attr,old,new

    last_clicked_ID = list(set(old)^set(new))[0] # [0] since there will always be just one different element at a time
    print 'last button clicked:', a.labels[last_clicked_ID]
    last_clicked_button_stuff = stuff_list[last_clicked_ID]
    in_active = last_clicked_ID in new
    last_clicked_button_stuff(in_active)

a.on_change('active',do_stuff)

curdoc().add_root(a)
```

Or you can loop through the buttons and do stuff with all the buttons each time a button is clicked:

```
def do_stuff(attr,old,new):
    print attr,old,new

    for i in [0,1,2]:
        stuff = stuff_list[i]
        in_active = i in new
        stuff(in_active)
```

Comment: When you say checkboxgroup callback do you mean the `callback` attribute (where I need to make a CustomJS object?)  or can I do this in the `on_click` function that I set for my checkboxgroup object (wasn't able to find out how I can reference the individual button just clicked within the `on_click` function)?

Comment: @hhprogram please see the edit, you don't need on_click events with a CheckboxButtonGroup. Those are not really buttons, it's a list of checkboxes displayed as buttons, just one bokeh model. You can only interact with the changes to the list of checked boxes / clicked buttons.